# C++ dangling const reference to a temporary object

Tags: c++, reference, boost-filesystem

Why is there a dangling reference in the following code? I've thought that references to const always extend the lifespan of a temporary to their scope.

```
boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator it(dir_name);
const std::string& extension = it->path().extension().string();
std::cout << extension << std::endl; // error, dangling reference
```

Comment: "[...]References to const always extend the lifespan of a temporary to their scope". Why would they ?

Comment: What tells you it's a dangling reference there??

Comment: @JBL: Because the language standard says they do. As long as the initialiser actually is a temporary.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh thanks ! Could you point the section ? (I can't find to which it is related).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) for `class path`:

> Member functions described as returning `const string` are permitted to return `const string&`

So there's no guarantee that `string()` actually returns a temporary string. It may be a reference to a string inside the temporary `path` returned by `extension()`; that will *not* have its lifetime extended, since it is *not* directly bound to a local reference.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make `extension` a const ref. Do this instead:

```
const std::string extension = it->path().extension().string();
```

Comment: I think the asker understands this possibility, but is wondering why their code doesn't behave like the [most important `const`](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).